# Can someone explain why there is no output?

Tags: python

sorry for the vague title. I'm wondering why, when I enter "look around", nothing happens. The code stays running but doesn't output anything as it should.

````
        if PlayerPos==51: # Inside cottage
            choice=input("You stand in the middle of the small, neat home, what do you do?")
            checker=choice.lower().split()
            for word in checker:
                if word in directions:
                    print("You can move no further")
            if choice.lower()=="go outside"or"go out"or"exit":
                PlayerPos=0
            elif choice.lower()=="look around":
                print("You find two bread loafs and a small kitchen knife")
                inventory.append("Bread Loaf")
                inventory.append("Bread Loaf")
                inventory.append("Kitchen Knife")
                print(inventory)
                continue
            else:
                print("I don't understand. Please reword your command")
                continue```
````

Comment: If will never reach that comparison for the reasons explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: `if choice.lower() in {"go outside", "go out", "exit"}:`.

Comment: `if choice.lower() in ["go outside", "go out", "exit"]:`